# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I get the below error when I ran the below code. May I know what is wrong in my code. Thanks in advance . I am using hibernate and java

HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Session session = null;
Transaction tx = null;

    public String getEntityList(String userIds, String callerID) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    List<User> userList = session.createCriteria(User.class)
            .list();
    //Query the database
    CallableStatement stmt = null;
    String returnVal = "";

    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        stmt = ((Connection) session).prepareCall("{?=call WS_Distributionlist(?,?)}");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {





        // left over accounts processing
            stmt.executeUpdate();

            returnVal += stmt.getString(1) + "|";
            System.out.println("RETURN VALUE in tail end :::::: "
                    + returnVal);

        //returnVal = returnVal.substring(0, returnVal.length() - 1);

        System.out.println("Return Value " + returnVal);
        session.close();

        //return returnVal;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while executing the database function ");
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }


    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: Could you filter out the code from the unnecessary blank rows and try to localize the problem somehow?

Comment: It would be easy to read the code if it is indended

Comment: How much memory did you give for your application? What does your stored procedure `WS_Distributionlist ` do? How many rows do you expect from the query?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of useful details are missing:

1. `userIds` is an input parameter of the function where is it used?
2. `userList`, how many users are there and where are they used?
3. `WS_Distributionlist(?,?)` has 2 input parameters, where do you set them?

I cannot understand the following line of code:
`((Connection) session).prepareCall("{?=call WS_Distributionlist(?,?)}");`

I've seen and used many technique to get a connection out of an hibernate session, none of which where casting the session itself to connection, but this is more or less a personal curiosity.

The point is that there is a lot of missing code, so I can just speculate that one of this calls produces an huge dataset, or that you are passing some huge parameter to a statement.

Either way, if you deal with HUGE dataset you should probably use a StatelessSession , because stateless session have nearly zero memory overhead (no caching).

If you build your own statement from connection , use FORWARD_ONLY_CURSOR.

Try setting the fetchSize on the statements that returns resultset.

Consider using either a ScrollableResult or an Iterator instead of a List as a result.